# how can I reduce usage of resources in kafka connect? is there any option to increase the refresh interval?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka-Influxdb connector and for now, It is enough for me to refresh the Kafka topic in a 1-minute interval but I can't find any option to change the refresh time

Comment: there is 2 option for kafka producer: Batch Size and Linger Time but I don't know how can I set them for a connector

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override producer properties (`linger.ms` in your case) for a specific connector, enable client overrides in the worker configuration and then use `producer.override.*` for a source connector config:

> `"producer.override.linger.ms": "0"`

Source: [*Kafka Connect Worker Configuration Properties: Override the Worker Configuration*](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-the-worker-configuration)